# allias in htaccess does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

I found a lot of documentation on this and other questions, but I just couldn't manage to fix this. Help is much appreciated :-)

On my website I need a alias for a certain page.

http://www.example.com/sign-up

Needs to load the following page: 
http://www.example.com/abo/myplace/sign-up

I tried to fix this with the following htaccess rules:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sign-up
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /abo/myplace/sign-up [L,P]
```

Also I tried with only [P], then the same problem occurs. The page redirects to the other url, it's not an alias.

Anybody got any tips? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^sign-up$ abo/myplace/sign-up
```

Comment: Could you please add more information on why this would help answering the question?

Comment: Thanks! This did work. No problem that it's a short answer, it's correct :-)